# Change access to different fields of a model depending on user roles in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have two user roles admin and user. I also have a model vehicle, which only admin can create. For that I use `preAuthorize`  in spring boot. Admin also can edit any attribute of the vehicle model. But I want the normal user to edit some attributes but not all the attributes. How can I do this in spring boot. I have implemented spring security in my application.

So when a Normal user tries to update vehicle details, I need to make sure, the user hasn't change the attributes which that user don't have permission to access.

Comment: Are you using controllers ? I am assuming you are using controllers and admin are using these controllers to edit the data in backend. You can pass Principal as a parameter in the controllers. Then in the controllers you can use conditionals to check whether the principal is  a admin or user. Based on this condition you can prevent users from accessing certain attributes.

Comment: I'm using rest controllers. I was wondering whether i can do that using spring security or spring validation.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this can be to store authority to `JsonView` information via an annotation. Then use this data as metadata to select appropriate `SerializationView` in a subclass of `AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice`. HI have prepared a sample project hosted at [github](https://github.com/gourav/spring-security-filter-fields-per-role-sample).

`AuthorityToJsonViewMapping` allows to store a map of role to json view to be accessible at run time.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface AuthorityToJsonViewMapping {

  String authority();
  Class<?> view();

}
```

`AuthorityToJsonViewMappings` allows to store multiple such mappings.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface AuthorityToJsonViewMappings {

  AuthorityToJsonViewMapping[] value();

}
```

Now, we only have to write a `RestControllerAdvice` to retrieve current user's authorities and determine appropriate view as per configured object's class. This code has room to cache mappings against a domain class against an authority.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RoleBasedJsonSerializationControllerAdvice extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice {

  @Override
  protected void beforeBodyWriteInternal(MappingJacksonValue bodyContainer, MediaType contentType, MethodParameter returnType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

    Authentication currentAuthentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    Class<?> bodyClass = bodyContainer.getValue().getClass();
    AuthorityToJsonViewMappings mappings = bodyClass.getAnnotation(AuthorityToJsonViewMappings.class);

    if(mappings == null) {
      return;
    }

    Map<String, Class<?>> authorityToViewMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (AuthorityToJsonViewMapping authorityToJsonViewMapping : mappings.value()) {
      authorityToViewMap.put(authorityToJsonViewMapping.authority(), authorityToJsonViewMapping.view());
    }

    for (GrantedAuthority authority : currentAuthentication.getAuthorities()) {

      if(authorityToViewMap.get(authority.getAuthority()) != null) {
        bodyContainer.setSerializationView(authorityToViewMap.get(authority.getAuthority()));
        return;

      }
    }

  }
}
```

This allows us to store this mapping against each of the domain class.

```
@AuthorityToJsonViewMappings({
  @AuthorityToJsonViewMapping(authority = "USER", view = Item.WithoutOwnerView.class),
  @AuthorityToJsonViewMapping(authority = "ADMIN", view = Item.WithOwnerView.class)
})
public class Item {

  @JsonView(WithoutOwnerView.class)
  private int id;

  @JsonView(WithoutOwnerView.class)
  private String name;

  @JsonView(WithOwnerView.class)
  private String owner;

  public interface WithoutOwnerView {};
  public interface WithOwnerView extends WithoutOwnerView {};

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
  }

  public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
  }
}
```

And controller is free to only implement Controller-esque tasks.

```
@RestController
public class ItemController {

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Item> getItem() {

    Item item = new Item();
    item.setId(1);
    item.setName("item");
    item.setOwner("_gaurav");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(item);
  }

}
```